# How to swap / invert the RMB (that activates the "object context menu") with the LMB (that selects an object) in 2.8

Tags: customization

I would like to swap / invert the right mouse button (that activates the "object context menu") with the left mouse button (that selects an object). how can I do that ? I see that this can be chosen on the splash screen,but when it starts on my blender 2.8,I don't see the chance to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Edit > Preferences > Keymap > • Select with

Comment: I've inverted the mouse buttons,now I can select the object with the RMB,BUT when I press the LMB the "object context menu" does not appear anymore.